# Firebase Android read data -> processing->update data "Global variable problem"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to take data from Firebase and remove delete some value and then save the data to Firebase. Here is my read function in my Activity:

```
 private void readData() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    currentUserDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String,Object> map = (Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
             kwotaKonta= ((String)map.get("account"));
```

When I make everything in "onDataChange" it's removed over and over so
I tried to create global variable named "kwotaKonta" and make it onCreate but when function is over "kwotaKonta" is null. How can I get the value from `onDataChange`?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its remove over and over

This is happening because you are using `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. The `ValueEventListener` is triggered every time something changes in your database. So if you remove something from the database, your `onDataChange()` method fires again.

To solve this, please change:

```
currentUserDB.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

to

```
currentUserDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) pelase see:

> addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListener listener) - Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.

and

> addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener listener) - Add a listener for changes in the data at this location.